# Laravel boot method updating not working in the model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 9, updating/upated boot method not working. When I use deleting then updating/upated boot method running to update delete_at and deleted_by field value but when I try to update any thing doesn't work.

```
self::updating(function ($model) {
   $user = Auth::user();
   $model->updated_by = $user->id;
});
```

```
$data = array(
    'title'         =>  $request->title,
    'account_type'  =>  $request->account_type
);
Head::find($request->head_id)->update($data);
```

Comment: any errors ? Did you call `parent::boot()` before the other lines of code ?

Comment: yes, I call but not working, deleting and creating works fine

Comment: may [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484621/laravel-model-event-updating-not-firing) could hep

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
self::updating(function ($model) {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $model->updated_by = $user->id;
    $model->save();
});
```

The save() function is required to save record.